# Visual Studio Find and Replace with Regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, replace

I want to replace C# attributes with VB.NET, which means, `[Serializable]` should become `<Serializable>`.

The pattern `(\[)(.+)(\])` does find the results but I don't know how to replace the first and the last groups with the appropriate parenthesis.

I read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx) page, but I didn't understand how to use the curly braces for F&R, I tried to wrap the groups with it but it didn't work.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio 2010 I would recommend installing the Productivity Power Tools extension from Microsoft. This has a search/replace which supports normal .NET regular expressions.

Comment: I am using the PPT extension. I don't know how to replace with it (I did try the classic F&R and it didn't work either).

Comment: If Quick Find is enabled in the PPT options page, just pressing Ctrl+H should open the replace dialog. Pressing the drop-down arrow in the "find" text-box should display some options allowing you to enable regular expressions. Additional info can be found for example at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/03/15/quick-find-extension-in-the-productivity-power-tools.aspx

Comment: @DeCaf (@R2D2) I know how to use it. My question is how to replace with regex.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question. Posted an answer below which should work using the Quick Find/Replace from PTT.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using the Productivity Power Tools extension from Microsoft that support normal .NET regexes, what you would put in the textbox for the replacement given your regular expression above is:

```
<$2>
```

where `$2` refers to the second capture group in your regex, i.e. the text between the brackets.

Note that this only works with the Quick Find from Productivity Power Tools though. The normal find/replace in Visual Studio use another syntax altogether.

Comment: And what is the syntax for the normal F&R?

Comment: Thank you so much for this note: "where $2 refers to the second capture group in your regex". It really helped me a lot when solving my regex replace issue.

Answer (score 1):

Find what:             \[{Serializable}\]

Replace with:          <\1>